# VARCHAR values that contain single double quotes are exported with two double quotes in Web UI?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with VARCHAR field that has a value like `A "B" C`. When I click "Download Results" in the Web UI and inspect the resulting CSV or TSV file, the value returned is `A ""B"" C`, meaning the sets of quotes have been duplicated. Note that I do not see this issue with a COPY INTO statement (exported to S3).

To replicate this issue easily, you can run the following in a Snowflake Web Console session and download the results to CSV:

```
    SELECT 'A "B" C' AS QUOTE_FIELD ;
```

Note that double quotes are simply duplicated, so an example of two double quotes (`A ""B"" C`) would export as `A """"B"""" C`.

Does anyone know of a way to resolve this unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

In CLI, it produces the expected result.

A "B" C

[image]

Comment: Thanks sridark - the CLI and web console produce expected results. It's only when I export to a csv/tsv from the Web UI that I see this.

Answer (score 0):

hey TSV export looks good, but not csv.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please open a Snowflake Support ticket for this.

Comment: Hi Suzy - thanks, I have a Snowflake support ticket open.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly note that the double quote you are noticing in the CSV file is expected. By default, the escape character is a " (double quote) for CSV-formatted files.

When you import the same data into the Snowflake table, you can also specify the escape character as such so that it parses the data as expected and lod in to the table.

For more details, please refer https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#type-csv

Comment: No, it is a bug.  Either the field should be exported as "A ""B"" C", or A "B" C, which is imported correctly in Excel, but A ""B"" C does not import as the original result set.